# Why is "New Incognito Window" disabled in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I'm trying to use an incognito window so that I can test have a clean slate on cookies without restarting my browser.  Unfortunately, incognito windows are disabled for some reason.  Does anyone know why that is?  I'm on Windows 7 using Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simply add the following dword entry in the registry as [this link](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoModeAvailability) describes:

Windows registry location:

`Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\IncognitoModeAvailability`

Supported on:

```
Google Chrome (Linux, Mac, Windows) since version 14  
Google Chrome OS (Google Chrome OS) since version 0.14
```

Description:

```
Specifies whether the user may open pages in Incognito mode in Google Chrome. If 'Enabled' is selected, pages may be opened in Incognito mode. If 'Disabled' is selected, pages may not be opened in Incognito mode. If 'Forced' is selected, pages may be opened ONLY in Incognito mode. 
0 = Incognito mode available. 
1 = Incognito mode disabled. 
2 = Incognito mode forced.
```

If this is a work system, then the creation and maintenance of this key (and in turn the availability of the option) may be under the control of your network admin.

Comment: Ahh, it must be disabled on my work system.  That's too bad since it hinders my development.  +1 for the info, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

@ukanth way is right and to save-up some more time you can copy the below text and save it in a text file and rename it to ***some_name.reg***

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"IncognitoModeAvailability"=dword:00000000
```

Later you can double click this file to enable incognito mode.

*(Tested and working fine in Windows 10)*

Answer (score -1):

How To Enable Incognito Mode In Windows

First, open the registry editor:

Open the Start menu
In the search box, type "regedit"
A program called regedit.exe will appear, click on this
If a warning comes up click Yes
Next, navigate to the Policies key:

Start by double clicking on "Computer"
Then, double click on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
Next, double click on "SOFTWARE"
Finally, double click on "Policies"
Next, create a new entry called IncognitoModeAvailability:

Right-click on "Policies" and select New >> Key
Enter "Google" (without the quotes) as the name of the key
Right-click on "Google" and select New >> Key
Enter "Chrome" (without the quotes) as the name of the key
Right-click on "Chrome" and select New >> DWORD (32-bit) Value
Enter "IncognitoModeAvailability" (without the quotes) as the name
Right-click on "IncognitoModeAvailability" and select "Modify..."
Type a 0 in the "Value Data" text box

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP already has Incognito disabled. Has wants to enable it. The accepted answer show how to do this.