# Why is Incognito mode disabled in Google Chrome on my mac?

Tags: private-browsing

I am trying to enable incognito mode in Google Chrome on my MacBook. However, the option is greyed out in the drop down menu. Why is it disabled and how can I enable it?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/419643/31641. (Not a duplicate question, as all answers there are for Windows, but it might give you some clues of places to start looking.)

Answer (score 1):

It might have been disabled at the system preferences level, possibly by another admin user on your machine. [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186026/how-to-disable-incognito-mode-in-chrome) explains how to **DISABLE** it.

I assume that to **ENABLE** it again, you must set the `IncognitoModeAvailability` to a value of `0`

Comment: Weird. The normal way too disable stuff is 0 for false. I'll confirm this as I was struck by this issue too.